# Difference between max units and assignment units in MS Project

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, ms-project-2010

I know difference between assignment units and Peak units , but can any one explain how max units and assignment units are related to each other ?

Answer (score 1):

Max. Units is set on a resource level - usually in the Resource Sheet view.  When assigning a resource, Project will, by default, use the max units as the assignment units value.  However, you can assign a resource at any value - below or above - the max units manually.  If a resource's Peak Units exceed Max Units - the resource is overallocated.